# Paypal Payment Failure for Recurring Payment API IPN's txn_type

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am implementing Recurring Payment API with Paypal Pro. My question is when a payment fails, and i receive an IPN, what will be its txn_type? And what all IPN's i'll be expecting? so that i can take care of then in my IPNhandler class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Possible txn_type's you can get when using Recurring Payments consist of:

recurring_payment_profile_created

recurring_payment_profile_cancel

recurring_payment_profile_modify

recurring_payment

recurring_payment_skipped

recurring_payment_failed

recurring_payment_suspended_due_to_max_failed_payment

In most cases when a payment fails you'll get the skipped notification.  I very rarely see an actual failed notification.  I've never gotten any answers as to why that is.

Here are some samples.

```
Array
(
    [payment_cycle] => Monthly
    [txn_type] => recurring_payment_skipped
    [last_name] => Testerson
    [next_payment_date] => 03:00:00 Oct 24, 2012 PDT
    [residence_country] => US
    [initial_payment_amount] => 0.00
    [rp_invoice_id] => 3250
    [currency_code] => USD
    [time_created] => 15:42:49 Sep 19, 2012 PDT
    [verify_sign] => AH1WkYze3JQ1xNtDm31SsDJxLeGrAxPpeVKBrMHLFmRVOWXnZep95xOm
    [period_type] =>  Regular
    [payer_status] => unverified
    [test_ipn] => 1
    [tax] => 0.00
    [payer_email] => test@hey.com
    [first_name] => Tester
    [receiver_email] => usb_1329725429_biz@angelleye.com
    [payer_id] => TP7CXHP6TVNSS
    [product_type] => 1
    [shipping] => 0.00
    [amount_per_cycle] => 1.95
    [profile_status] => Active
    [charset] => windows-1252
    [notify_version] => 3.7
    [amount] => 1.95
    [outstanding_balance] => 0.00
    [recurring_payment_id] => I-0SAH6FDN3JJA
    [product_name] => USBSwiper Monthly Subscription
    [ipn_track_id] => f2380796ce7c
)



Array
(
    [payment_cycle] => Monthly
    [txn_type] => recurring_payment_failed
    [last_name] => Garcia
    [next_payment_date] => 02:00:00 Feb 12, 2012 PST
    [residence_country] => US
    [initial_payment_amount] => 0.00
    [rp_invoice_id] => 939
    [currency_code] => USD
    [time_created] => 16:29:33 Jan 29, 2010 PST
    [verify_sign] => A5rGTRcXhg6p48uIMYaPQKo7dsKqAO89FRXvCmuAfV5EYGWkAAD0vbPc
    [period_type] =>  Regular
    [payer_status] => unverified
    [tax] => 0.00
    [payer_email] => testpayer@hey.com
    [first_name] => Maria
    [receiver_email] => testreceiver@hey.com
    [payer_id] => EJ8JBQ63VHECL
    [product_type] => 1
    [shipping] => 0.00
    [amount_per_cycle] => 4.95
    [profile_status] => Active
    [charset] => windows-1252
    [notify_version] => 3.4
    [amount] => 4.95
    [outstanding_balance] => 14.85
    [recurring_payment_id] => I-S3APFHH0KFJ2
    [product_name] => USBSwiper Monthly Subscription
    [ipn_track_id] => Gi2zp.DfhsYitm8Kd0Dn3g
)

Array
(
    [payment_cycle] => Monthly
    [txn_type] => recurring_payment_suspended_due_to_max_failed_payment
    [last_name] => Nom_3
    [next_payment_date] => N/A
    [residence_country] => CA
    [initial_payment_amount] => 0.00
    [rp_invoice_id] => 3245
    [currency_code] => USD
    [time_created] => 10:53:25 Mar 14, 2012 PDT
    [verify_sign] => AptDZCkTZINE6OhArrkjyIYauY8GAGO.XoBdyMW5t7SoHPSC8DOFS9kB
    [period_type] =>  Regular
    [payer_status] => unverified
    [test_ipn] => 1
    [tax] => 0.00
    [payer_email] => sandbox@hey.com
    [first_name] => Prenom_3
    [receiver_email] => usb_1329725429_biz@angelleye.com
    [payer_id] => TP7CXHP6TVNSS
    [product_type] => 1
    [shipping] => 0.00
    [amount_per_cycle] => 1.95
    [profile_status] => Suspended
    [charset] => windows-1252
    [notify_version] => 3.4
    [amount] => 1.95
    [outstanding_balance] => 1.95
    [recurring_payment_id] => I-CEBHH0K0V7T1
    [product_name] => USBSwiper Monthly Subscription
    [ipn_track_id] => d09d07fdd833
)

Array
(
    [mc_gross] => 1.95
    [period_type] =>  Regular
    [outstanding_balance] => 0.00
    [next_payment_date] => 03:00:00 Aug 18, 2013 PDT
    [protection_eligibility] => Ineligible
    [payment_cycle] => Monthly
    [address_status] => confirmed
    [tax] => 0.00
    [payer_id] => E7BTGVXBFSUAU
    [address_street] => 1 Main St
    [payment_date] => 05:00:34 Jul 18, 2013 PDT
    [payment_status] => Completed
    [product_name] => USBSwiper Monthly Subscription
    [charset] => windows-1252
    [rp_invoice_id] => 3275
    [recurring_payment_id] => I-R0KGNCTUYAVW
    [address_zip] => 95131
    [first_name] => Drew
    [mc_fee] => 0.15
    [address_country_code] => US
    [address_name] => Drew Angell's Test Store
    [notify_version] => 3.7
    [amount_per_cycle] => 1.95
    [payer_status] => verified
    [currency_code] => USD
    [business] => usb_1329725429_biz@angelleye.com
    [address_country] => United States
    [address_city] => San Jose
    [verify_sign] => AOX9jItnq2qBtXeyCB5nhWVdWyqEAScu5FToCodROuhjlKYjtDeAdlmL
    [payer_email] => sandbo_1204199080_biz@angelleye.com
    [initial_payment_amount] => 0.00
    [profile_status] => Active
    [amount] => 1.95
    [txn_id] => 9PD943662S291292G
    [payment_type] => instant
    [payer_business_name] => Drew Angell's Test Store
    [last_name] => Angell
    [address_state] => CA
    [receiver_email] => usb_1329725429_biz@angelleye.com
    [payment_fee] => 0.15
    [receiver_id] => C9TAVNJFATXCS
    [txn_type] => recurring_payment
    [mc_currency] => USD
    [residence_country] => US
    [test_ipn] => 1
    [transaction_subject] => USBSwiper Monthly Subscription
    [payment_gross] => 1.95
    [shipping] => 0.00
    [product_type] => 1
    [time_created] => 15:10:22 Jun 18, 2013 PDT
    [ipn_track_id] => 28067cf6ae8f
)

Array
(
    [payment_cycle] => Monthly
    [txn_type] => recurring_payment_profile_created
    [last_name] => Angell
    [next_payment_date] => 03:00:00 Jun 18, 2013 PDT
    [residence_country] => US
    [initial_payment_amount] => 0.00
    [rp_invoice_id] => 3275
    [currency_code] => USD
    [time_created] => 15:10:22 Jun 18, 2013 PDT
    [verify_sign] => ANrMRzzgbWP1I9ntjeVxAzQDTVjbATTckkxc4RtXKTYHoCoFDbklKPpd
    [period_type] =>  Regular
    [payer_status] => verified
    [test_ipn] => 1
    [tax] => 0.00
    [payer_email] => sandbo_1204199080_biz@angelleye.com
    [first_name] => Drew
    [receiver_email] => usb_1329725429_biz@angelleye.com
    [payer_id] => E7BTGVXBFSUAU
    [product_type] => 1
    [payer_business_name] => Drew Angell's Test Store
    [shipping] => 0.00
    [amount_per_cycle] => 1.95
    [profile_status] => Active
    [charset] => windows-1252
    [notify_version] => 3.7
    [amount] => 1.95
    [outstanding_balance] => 0.00
    [recurring_payment_id] => I-R0KGNCTUYAVW
    [product_name] => USBSwiper Monthly Subscription
    [ipn_track_id] => 1bf251e429b9c
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This makes a lot of sense. Now i know which cases to take care of. One more thing i am not sure about is if i get Recurring_Payment_Skipped IPN, is the Paypal going to add the amount in Outstanding Balance or not?

Comment: It'll go into outstanding balance, yes, and their system will automatically re-try in 5 days.  It will do this re-try 3 times, and if it fails on all 3 re-try attempts it will suspend the profile due to max failed payment and you'll get that notification.

Comment: Thank you, also can we reactivate a recurring profile if it is canceled over Paypal or from API using ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus?

Comment: If it's fully canceled you can't reactivate it.  You can only do that if it's suspended.

Comment: @AndrewAngell Just to clarify, when a payment fails and reaches the max number of failed payments, you'll get the fail notification and then the suspension notification?

Comment: @AndrewAngell thanks for the info... I still have one doubt: When do we get subscr_signup or subscr_payment? I don't see those in your list.

Comment: Those are related to standard subscriptions as opposed to recurring payments profiles.

Answer (score 0):

Same as [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1188826/andrew-angell), but expanding on how skips and fails work (from what I've seen.):

**recurring_payment_profile_created** - When the profile is created. Important to note the recurring_payment_id, this is what you'll need to cancel/suspend/modify the profile.

**recurring_payment_profile_cancel** - When the profile is canceled.

**recurring_payment_profile_modify** - When the profile is modified.

**recurring_payment** - When you receive a recurring payment.

**recurring_payment_skipped** - When PayPal failed to collect payment and will try again in 5 days.

**recurring_payment_failed** - When MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS is not set, PayPal will try 3 times, if it fails all three, this will be the 3rd IPN.

**recurring_payment_suspended_due_to_max_failed_payment** - When MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS is set, this will be the IPN instead of recurring_payment_failed when the max is reached.

Comment: Sorry for interrupting. If the MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS is not set or is set to 0, from the documentation it says Paypal will try to collect fund for unlimited number of tries. But in your answer, you said Paypal will try up to three times ? which one is correct ?

if MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS is set to 0 and Paypal fails to collect the fund in the third try, will Paypal suspend the profile ? If not what will happen to next recurring payment ? will be any outstanding amount for next recurring ?